# Tails for infected machine

Tags: tor

Would running Tails on an infected machine with Windows OS be best? Would it resolve the current malware rootkit RAT as you are on a separate OS?

As long as you use the Tails OS and don't go into the Windows OS it should be ok?

Comment: No it wouldn’t resolve it. In this case you should reinstall windows and remove the infection.

Comment: "be best" for what?

Comment: There is an extension of rootkits called bootkits which reside either in the bootsector or directly in the NVRAM. It is capable of compromising other OS also.

Answer (score 2):

Tails is a boot CD, so it runs irrespectively of what kind of OS you have on your machine and whether it is infected. Your machine might have no OS at all, and Tails would still run. It does not load the MBR from your hard disk either.

However if you happen to be infected with one of [UEFI rootkits](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2948092/security/hacking-teams-malware-uses-uefi-rootkit-to-survive-os-reinstalls.html), it might possibly compromise Tails.